# How to solve a Supply Chain Linear Programing model using lp_solve with nodeJS (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, linear-programming, lpsolve

I am trying to solve the Capacitated Plant Location Model from this [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBvf2AVqhPA) using `lp_solve`:

In Excel the objective function is done using SUMPRODUCT() and I developed this function in JavaScript to replicate it:

```js
// Sample data arrays
/* const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const array2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; */

// Function to calculate the sum product
export default function sumProduct(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    throw new Error('Arrays must have the same length');
  }
  
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    result += arr1[i] * arr2[i];
  }
  
  return result;
}

// Calculate the sum product
// const result = sumProduct(array1, array2); // OUTPUT: 70 (correct)
```

However I cannot set up the model properly using `lp_solve` because the sumProd require numbers for arrays but the Decision Variables array are strings for now. Excel can just compute the empty cells using the SUMPRODUCT() function, and I am wondering if I can achieve a similar functionality with the Javascript (`lp_solve`) model.

Or is there another way to set up the model?

Here is how I set it up:

```
import sumProduct  from "./sumProd.mjs";
import lp_solve from "lp_solve";

// Create a new LP model
const lp = new lp_solve.LinearProgram();

// Supply and demand locations
const locations = ["N_America", "S_America", "NCE", "MED", "APAC"];

// Transportation costs matrix
const transportationCosts = [
  [81, 92, 101, 130, 115],
  [117, 77, 108, 98, 100],
  [102, 105, 95, 119, 111],
  [115, 125, 90, 59, 74],
  [142, 100, 103, 105, 71],
];

// Fixed costs and capacities
const Fixed_Costs_L = [6000, 4500, 6500, 4100, 4000];
const Low_Capacity = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
const Fixed_Costs_H = [9000, 6750, 9750, 6150, 6000];
const High_Capacity = [20, 20, 20, 20, 20];

// Demand values for each location
const demand = [12, 8, 14, 16, 7];

// Create an object to store indices for demand locations
const demandIndices = {};
locations.forEach((location, index) => {
  demandIndices[location] = index;
});

// Add binary variables for opening/closing plants
const openPlants = {};
for (const location of locations) {
  openPlants[location] = lp.addColumn(`Open_${location}`, true, false);  // Indicate integer variable with 0/1 values
}


// Add columns (variables) for supply and demand allocations
const allocation = {};
for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
  allocation[supplyLocation] = {};

  for (const demandLocation of locations) {
    allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation] = lp.addColumn(`${supplyLocation}_${demandLocation}`, true, true); // Indicate integer variable
  }

}

// Add constraints to ensure supply meets demand
for (const demandLocation of locations) {
  const demandConstraint = new lp_solve.Row();
  for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
    demandConstraint.Add(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation], 1);
  }
  lp.addConstraint(demandConstraint, "EQ", demand[demandIndices[demandLocation]], `Demand_${demandLocation}`);

}

// Add constraints for plant capacity based on the binary decision variable
for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
  const capacityConstraint = new lp_solve.Row();

  capacityConstraint.Add(openPlants[supplyLocation], High_Capacity[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)]);
  capacityConstraint.Add(openPlants[supplyLocation], Low_Capacity[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)]);
  
  for (const demandLocation of locations) {
    capacityConstraint.Subtract(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation], 1);
  }

  lp.addConstraint(capacityConstraint, "GE", 0, `Excess_Capacity_${supplyLocation}`);

}

// Add constraints to ensure supply and demand allocations are non-negative
for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
  for (const demandLocation of locations) {
    const nonNegativeConstraint = new lp_solve.Row();
    nonNegativeConstraint.Add(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation], 1);
    lp.addConstraint(nonNegativeConstraint, "GE", 0, `NonNegative_${supplyLocation}_${demandLocation}`);
  }
}

// Set the objective function to minimize total cost
const objective = new lp_solve.Row();
for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
  for (const demandLocation of locations) {
    objective.Add(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation], transportationCosts[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)][locations.indexOf(demandLocation)]);
  }
  objective.Add(openPlants[supplyLocation], Fixed_Costs_L[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)]);
  objective.Add(openPlants[supplyLocation], Fixed_Costs_H[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)]);
}
lp.setObjective(objective, true); // true indicates minimizing

// Solve the LP optimization problem
const result = lp.solve();

console.log(lp.dumpProgram());
console.log(lp.solve());

// Display the results
if (result.description === "OPTIMAL") {
  console.log("Solution found:");
  for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
    for (const demandLocation of locations) {
      const value = lp.get(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation]);
      if (value > 0) {
        console.log(`${supplyLocation} -> ${demandLocation}: ${value}`);
      }
    }
    const openValue = lp.get(openPlants[supplyLocation]);
    console.log(`${supplyLocation} Open: ${openValue}`);
  }
  console.log(`Total Cost: $${lp.getObjectiveValue()}`);
} else {
  console.log("No feasible solution found.");
}
```

What am I missing? Please help!

---

---

When ran, the model output an objective function like this, which is incorrect:

`minimize: +81 N_America_N_America +92 N_America_S_America +101 N_America_NCE +130 N_America_MED +115 N_America_APAC +15000 Open_N_America +117 S_America_N_America +77 S_America_S_America +108 S_America_NCE +98 S_America_MED +100 S_America_APAC +11250 Open_S_America +102 NCE_N_America +105 NCE_S_America +95 NCE_NCE +119 NCE_MED +111 NCE_APAC +16250 Open_NCE +115 MED_N_America +125 MED_S_America +90 MED_NCE +59 MED_MED +74 MED_APAC +10250 Open_MED +142 APAC_N_America +100 APAC_S_America +103 APAC_NCE +105 APAC_MED +71 APAC_APAC +10000 Open_APAC;`

The constraints seem okay, don't they?:

```
Demand_N_America:  +1 N_America_N_America +1 S_America_N_America +1 NCE_N_America +1 MED_N_America +1 APAC_N_America = 12;
Demand_S_America:  +1 N_America_S_America +1 S_America_S_America +1 NCE_S_America +1 MED_S_America +1 APAC_S_America = 8;
Demand_NCE:  +1 N_America_NCE +1 S_America_NCE +1 NCE_NCE +1 MED_NCE +1 APAC_NCE = 14;
Demand_MED:  +1 N_America_MED +1 S_America_MED +1 NCE_MED +1 MED_MED +1 APAC_MED = 16;
Demand_APAC:  +1 N_America_APAC +1 S_America_APAC +1 NCE_APAC +1 MED_APAC +1 APAC_APAC = 7;
Excess_Capacity_N_America:  +30 Open_N_America -1 N_America_N_America -1 N_America_S_America -1 N_America_NCE -1 N_America_MED -1 N_America_APAC >= 0;
Excess_Capacity_S_America:  +30 Open_S_America -1 S_America_N_America -1 S_America_S_America -1 S_America_NCE -1 S_America_MED -1 S_America_APAC >= 0;
Excess_Capacity_NCE:  +30 Open_NCE -1 NCE_N_America -1 NCE_S_America -1 NCE_NCE -1 NCE_MED -1 NCE_APAC >= 0;
Excess_Capacity_MED:  +30 Open_MED -1 MED_N_America -1 MED_S_America -1 MED_NCE -1 MED_MED -1 MED_APAC >= 0;
Excess_Capacity_APAC:  +30 Open_APAC -1 APAC_N_America -1 APAC_S_America -1 APAC_NCE -1 APAC_MED -1 APAC_APAC >= 0;
NonNegative_N_America_N_America:  +1 N_America_N_America >= 0;
NonNegative_N_America_S_America:  +1 N_America_S_America >= 0;
NonNegative_N_America_NCE:  +1 N_America_NCE >= 0;
NonNegative_N_America_MED:  +1 N_America_MED >= 0;
NonNegative_N_America_APAC:  +1 N_America_APAC >= 0;
NonNegative_S_America_N_America:  +1 S_America_N_America >= 0;
NonNegative_S_America_S_America:  +1 S_America_S_America >= 0;
NonNegative_S_America_NCE:  +1 S_America_NCE >= 0;
NonNegative_S_America_MED:  +1 S_America_MED >= 0;
NonNegative_S_America_APAC:  +1 S_America_APAC >= 0;
NonNegative_NCE_N_America:  +1 NCE_N_America >= 0;
NonNegative_NCE_S_America:  +1 NCE_S_America >= 0;
NonNegative_NCE_NCE:  +1 NCE_NCE >= 0;
NonNegative_NCE_MED:  +1 NCE_MED >= 0;
NonNegative_NCE_APAC:  +1 NCE_APAC >= 0;
NonNegative_MED_N_America:  +1 MED_N_America >= 0;
NonNegative_MED_S_America:  +1 MED_S_America >= 0;
NonNegative_MED_NCE:  +1 MED_NCE >= 0;
NonNegative_MED_MED:  +1 MED_MED >= 0;
NonNegative_MED_APAC:  +1 MED_APAC >= 0;
NonNegative_APAC_N_America:  +1 APAC_N_America >= 0;
NonNegative_APAC_S_America:  +1 APAC_S_America >= 0;
NonNegative_APAC_NCE:  +1 APAC_NCE >= 0;
NonNegative_APAC_MED:  +1 APAC_MED >= 0;
NonNegative_APAC_APAC:  +1 APAC_APAC >= 0;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have formulated your program slightly incorrectly, and also had some paramaters wrong. For a solution to this problem you need 35 decision variables (5x5=25 for transportation allocation, 5 for low production factorys and 5 for high production factorys.) You have combined the last 10 in to 5.

Additionally, you have the `isBinary` flag inverted for `addColumn` calls.

Below is a working solution to the video's problem.

```
const lp_solve = require("lp_solve");

// Create a new LP model
const lp = new lp_solve.LinearProgram();

// Supply and demand locations
const locations = ["N_America", "S_America", "NCE", "MED", "APAC"];

// Transportation costs matrix
const transportationCosts = [
  [81, 92, 101, 130, 115],
  [117, 77, 108, 98, 100],
  [102, 105, 95, 119, 111],
  [115, 125, 90, 59, 74],
  [142, 100, 103, 105, 71],
];

// Fixed costs and capacities
const Fixed_Costs_L = [6000, 4500, 6500, 4100, 4000];
const Low_Capacity = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
const Fixed_Costs_H = [9000, 6750, 9750, 6150, 6000];
const High_Capacity = [20, 20, 20, 20, 20];

// Demand values for each location
const demand = [12, 8, 14, 16, 7];

// Create an object to store indices for demand locations
const demandIndices = {};
locations.forEach((location, index) => {
  demandIndices[location] = index;
});

// Add binary variables for opening/closing plants
const highPlants = {};
const lowPlants = {};
for (const location of locations) {
    highPlants[location] = lp.addColumn(`Open_${location}_high`, true, true);  // Indicate integer variable with 0/1 values
    lowPlants[location] = lp.addColumn(`Open_${location}_low`, true, true);  // Indicate integer variable with 0/1 values
}

// Add columns (variables) for supply and demand allocations
const allocation = {};
for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
  allocation[supplyLocation] = {};

  for (const demandLocation of locations) {
    allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation] = lp.addColumn(`${supplyLocation}_${demandLocation}`, true, false); // Indicate integer variable
  }
}

// Add constraints to ensure supply meets demand
for (const demandLocation of locations) {
  const demandConstraint = new lp_solve.Row();
  for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
    demandConstraint.Add(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation], 1);
  }
  lp.addConstraint(demandConstraint, "EQ", demand[demandIndices[demandLocation]], `Demand_${demandLocation}`);
}

// Add constraints for plant capacity based on the binary decision variable
for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
  const capacityConstraint = new lp_solve.Row();

  capacityConstraint.Add(highPlants[supplyLocation], High_Capacity[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)]);
  capacityConstraint.Add(lowPlants[supplyLocation], Low_Capacity[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)]);
  
  for (const demandLocation of locations) {
    capacityConstraint.Subtract(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation], 1);
  }

  lp.addConstraint(capacityConstraint, "GE", 0, `Excess_Capacity_${supplyLocation}`);
}

// Set the objective function to minimize total cost
const objective = new lp_solve.Row();
for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
  for (const demandLocation of locations) {
    objective.Add(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation], transportationCosts[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)][locations.indexOf(demandLocation)]);
  }
  objective.Add(lowPlants[supplyLocation], Fixed_Costs_L[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)]);
  objective.Add(highPlants[supplyLocation], Fixed_Costs_H[locations.indexOf(supplyLocation)]);
}

lp.setObjective(objective, true); // true indicates minimizing

console.log(lp.dumpProgram());

// Solve the LP optimization problem
const result = lp.solve();


// Display the results
if (result.description === "OPTIMAL") {
  console.log("Solution found:");
  for (const supplyLocation of locations) {
    for (const demandLocation of locations) {
      const value = lp.get(allocation[supplyLocation][demandLocation]);
      if (value > 0) {
        console.log(`${supplyLocation} -> ${demandLocation}: ${value}`);
      }
    }
    const openHighValue = lp.get(highPlants[supplyLocation]);
    console.log(`${supplyLocation} High Output: ${openHighValue}`);
    const openLowValue = lp.get(lowPlants[supplyLocation]);
    console.log(`${supplyLocation} Low Output: ${openLowValue}`);
  }
  console.log(`Total Cost: $${lp.getObjectiveValue()}`);
} else {
  console.log("No feasible solution found.");
}
```

And the output:

```
Solution found:
N_America High Output: 0
N_America Low Output: 0
S_America -> N_America: 12
S_America -> S_America: 8
S_America High Output: 1
S_America Low Output: 0
NCE High Output: 0
NCE Low Output: 0
MED -> NCE: 4
MED -> MED: 16
MED High Output: 1
MED Low Output: 0
APAC -> NCE: 10
APAC -> APAC: 7
APAC High Output: 1
APAC Low Output: 0
Total Cost: $23751
```

Hope this helps.